# Why is Chrome 40 rendering Ubuntu Web Font with faulty rsaquo and lsaquo?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, fonts

Since I updated Chrome from 39 something to version 40.0.2214.91 (64-bit) earlier this week I noticed that the Ubuntu web font I use on my site render some characters ugly.

The characters rendered ugly are `rsaquo` and `lsaquo` ('single right-pointing angle quotation mark' and 'single left-pointing angle quotation mark').

When ubuntu font is viewed in Chrome vs Safari:

[image: Chrome]

[image: Safari]

This happens on my computer MBP13 OSX 10.10.1 and I also have the font installed on my system.

Comment: It would probably be better to file this as a bug report for Chrom(ium), if it's present in the dev edition or nightlies as well.